# prevent 'index.php' from being accessible using Slimframework

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I'm using the Slimframework for my web app & i have all url request pointing to one entry point in 'index.php' using the following ReWrite in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

All is fine, however, `index.php` is still accessible in the url by way of the following request/route: 
`/mywebsite/public/index.php` which i DO NOT WANT. Now I understand that its the only file in my public html folder, but i do not want it accessible in the url... How can i redirect that to an erroneous route via

1) an .htaccess ReWrite

Or

2) some slim logic

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could update your rules like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Rewrite to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,E=rewritten:1]
# 404 any direct access of index.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:rewritten} !=1
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten} !=1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [R=404,L]
```

I removed the QSA flag which was not needed. I removed the file and directory checking, which was unnecessary, and replaced with a check for `index.php` which is quicker.

To answer your actual question I return a 404 for any attempt to access index.php directly. Another alternative would be to redirect to something.

Comment: how would i redirect to a specific route? rather than just a 404 forbidden page, i.e : RewriteRule ^ - www.mysite.com/error/errors

Comment: You could just use `ErrorDocument 404 /error/errors` so that would be served as the error page. Or I can update the code to redirect to that. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable external access to index.php, place the following code above your existing rules

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will return a Forbidden error if **/index.php** is direct accessed.

Comment: this is great but rather than return a forbidden error, how can i redirect this to a specific route? i.e : RewriteRule ^ - www.mysite.com/error/errors